# Jquery Find not in Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

I want the `.parent(#HELLO)`'s .child not having another .parent other than (#HELLO) to be clicked.

In THIS CASE the last yellow .child

BUT I'm getting all my children getting changed. I cannot use `child()` or `.last()` because I don't know if its going to be in last or not.

```js
var div = $('#HELLO');
$('button').click(function() {
  div.find('.child').addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: yellow;
}
#HELLO {
  width: 80%;
}
.hurted {
  background: green;
}
div.someuselessdivs {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  HURT ME MORE
</button>
<div id="HELLO" class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="someuselessdivs">
    <div class="child">
      ONLY I SHOULD BE CHANGED TO GREEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably best to remove the offensive text in you question if you want to garner any responses

Comment: In simple words `.child` should not be changed if it has a **closest** div with class = `'.parent` other than '#hello' div itself. *(P.S i cant check with #hello(i.e id) coz its just for explanation)*

Comment: oh ok removed that "offensive" word

Comment: I dont know why non of the solution worked for me. even tho they were right. I went with this   `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if (div.get(0) ===  $(this).closest(".parent").get(0) ){$(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
  });`

Comment: This is a really disturbing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask the parent div if it hasClass parent or not - I believe this is the most readable and pragmatic solution

```js
var div = $('#HELLO');
$('button').click(function() {
  div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if (!$(this).parent("div").hasClass("parent")) $(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: yellow;
}
#HELLO {
  width: 80%;
}
.hurted {
  background: green;
}
div.someuselessdivs {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  HURT ME MORE
</button>
<div id="HELLO" class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="someuselessdivs">
    <div class="child">
      ONLY I SHOULD BE CHANGED TO GREEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a better alternative than your convoluted and not recommended

> `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
>         if (div.get(0) === $(this).closest(".parent").get(0) ) {
>           $(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
>         }
>       });`

```js
var $rootDiv = $('#HELLO');
$('button').click(function() {
  $rootDiv.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).closest(".parent").is($rootDiv)) {
        $(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: yellow;
}
#HELLO {
  width: 80%;
}
.hurted {
  background: green;
}
div.someuselessdivs {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  HURT ME MORE
</button>
<div id="HELLO" class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="someuselessdivs">
    <div class="child">
      ONLY I SHOULD BE CHANGED TO GREEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know why non of the solution worked for me. even tho they were right. I went with this   `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if (div.get(0) ===  $(this).closest(".parent").get(0) ){$(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
  });`

Comment: That does not make any sense at all. If you run my snippet, it works - you must have a different setup than you posted

Comment: @EdwardSnowden So you are testing to see if the closest element with class parent is the top div instead of testing if the div you have does NOT have a parent div with class parent

Comment: @EdwardSnowden please see the update to add your method without testing HTML strings

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use the `:not` selector along with `.parent > .child` to exclude the relevant elements. Try this:

```js
var div = $('#HELLO');
$('button').click(function() {
  div.find('.child:not(.parent > .child)').addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: yellow;
}
#HELLO {
  width: 80%;
}
.hurted {
  background: green;
}
div.someuselessdivs {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  HURT ME MORE
</button>
<div id="HELLO" class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      I'M A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="someuselessdivs">
    <div class="child">
      ONLY I SHOULD BE CHANGED TO GREEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know why non of the solution worked for me. even tho they were right. I went with this   `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if (div.get(0) ===  $(this).closest(".parent").get(0) ){$(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
  });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to filter the results of a collection.

Here we get all `.child` withing `#HELLO` and then loop through the result with `each()` checking if the parent element has the class `.parent`. If not we add the class `.hurted`.

```js
$( 'button' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
  
  $( '#HELLO' ).find( '.child' ).each( function ( index, el ) {
  
    var $el = $( el );
  
    if ( !$el.parent().hasClass( 'parent' ) ) {
        $el.addClass( 'hurted' );
    }

  } );
  
} );
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: yellow;
}

#HELLO { 
  width: 80%;  
}
.hurted {
  background: green;
}
div.someuselessdivs {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>HURT ME MORE</button>

<div id="HELLO" class="parent">
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      IM A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME 
    </div> 
  </div>  
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      IM A CHILD OF PARENT OF PARENT DONT HURT ME 
    </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="someuselessdivs">
    <div class="child">   
      ONLY i SHOULD BE CHANGED TO GREEN
    </div>    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why write a filter when `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {` works just as well? - You are not even using the filter to return the child that needs to be changed

Comment: Nothing personal. You are abusing a side effect of the filter to set the class inside the loop instead of filtering and then set the class on the returned object

Comment: I dont know why non of the solution worked for me. even tho they were right. I went with this   `div.find('.child').each(function(i) {
    if (div.get(0) ===  $(this).closest(".parent").get(0) ){$(this).addClass('hurted').text('You hurt me!');
  });`